# Derive equation of motion with differently initial configuration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, conventions

I have a question about derivation equations of motion for a system.
For example with a cart and pole model. When I do google search, there are several configurations 
[image]

[image]

There are two different configurations (directions of the pitch angle), so the result is different. My question is which one is the correct configuration? how do we choose a correct configuration?

Comment: Define right configuration.

Comment: Are you asking how to choose coordinates/coordinate system/reference system?

Comment: @Qmechanic, as you can see, the initial angle of the upper image is on the left side, while the lower is on the right side. By this configurations, the results will be totally different. My question is which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right configuration". The definition of the angle may be different, the axis can be defined the other way or zero potencial can be anywhere else.

The lagrangian would be different then. However, if all is consistent, your answer will be correct in your configuration, no matter what configuration do you chose.

Comment: Could you please give some proofs that the modeling still correct? Any external link for this problem?

Comment: I won't solve it now, my sentence is general. For exemple, where do you consider zero gravitational potencial? For $theta=0$ or for $theta=\frac{p}{2}i$ (no matter what configuration I'm reffering to)? There's no correct answer, both are correct if you keep it in mind while solving the problem

Comment: Intuitively, the kinetic energy (translational motion) of the pendulum will be different between these configurations due to the initial position of the pendulum. That is why it made me confuse.